# DotNetOpenAuth OpenId Provider Intermittent issue while using with .Net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I was trying to use Sample application `OpenIdProviderWebForms Application` from DotNetOpenAuth-4.0.0.12084.

It was working fine with `OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms` when I used it as it is but suddenly I started getting following error

> Error while reading message
>   'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Messages.CheckIdRequest' parameter
>   'openid.claimed_id' with value
>   'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select'. Invalid cast
>   from 'System.String' to 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Identifier'. (Contact:
>   , Reference: )

It happened just after I moved the provider application to .Net 4.0 using visual studio(2010)'s project properties. I noticed it was Intermittent. It was not visible each time.

I need help to understand the issue.

BTW the problem was resolved when I moved back to .net 3.5...
But I need this to work on .Net 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved to DotNetOpenAuth v4.1.2.12274 and it was working...